# How to add social locker on custom fields

Tags: plugins

i want to add social locker on custom fields like demo and download buttons

```
<center><p><a class="mbutton" target="_blank" href="<?php echo get_field(demo_link); ?>">DEMO</a><p></center>
<center><p><a class="dbutton" target="_blank" href="<?php echo get_field(download_link); ?>">DOWNLOAD</a><p></center>
```

i tried to use `<?php echo do_shortcode("[lockercat]"); ?> added here buttons <?php echo do_shortcode("[/lockercat]"); ?>`

.....
with this locker works now but get_field function doesnt work and getting link like this

> example.com/post-name/php echo get_field(download_link); ?>

....

```
<?php
$lockit = '[lockercat]' . '<center><p><a class="mbutton" target="_blank" href="<?php echo get_field(demo_link); ?>">DEMO</a><p></center>
                            <center><p><a class="dbutton" target="_blank" href="<?php echo get_field(download_link); ?>">DOWNLOAD</a><p></center>' . '[/lockercat]';
echo do_shortcode($lockit);
?>
```

Comment: What's a social locker? Shortcodes have to be self contained, you can't pass `[shortcode`] in one call, then `[/shortcode]` in another

Answer (score 1):

The `do_shortcode()` syntax requires everything in one string.

```
<?php
$lockit = '[lockercat]' . 'your buttons etc.' . '[/lockercat]';
echo do_shortcode($lockit);
?>
```

Comment: The `"` quotes are unnecessary here, `$lockit` on its own is better, also your single quotes are broken

Comment: social locker works now but get_field function doesnt work.

Comment: Best to follow up with the plugin authors. This site is more for custom development rather than specific plugin troubleshooting.